# spl_autoload_register not showing namespace from my plugin while it showing from another plugins in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have researched about this but didn't find out anything so I am placing question.

I am creating a `WordPress` plugin and using a autoload class concept using `spl_autoload_register()` function but I can't able to get my own plugin classes but it's showing another plugin's classes.

This is my plugins folder structure.

```
-myplugin
  -assets
  -utility
  -controlling
  -includes
  -myplugin.php
  -plugin.php
```

---

```
<?php
namespace myplugin;

if(!defined('ABSPATH')):
    exit;
endif;

class Plugin{

    private static $_instance = null;

    public static function instance(){
        if(is_null(self::$_instance)):
            self::$_instance = new self();
        endif;

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function autoload($class){

        if(strpos($class, __NAMESPACE__) === false):
           return;
        endif;

        // This should be class from my plugin
        echo $class;



    }

    private function __construct(){
        spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
        spl_autoload_register( [$this, 'autoload'] );
    }
}

Plugin::instance();
```

`echo $class` should return class from my plugin but it's not showing. `__NAMESPACE__` showing the namespace of my class. Let me know if you want any more details about this in comment.